# How add elements to the JList parameterized by my own Type

Tags: java, swing, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have created a `JList` but it(and its' model) lacks `addElement` method. How to add instance of my class `Pacjent` to that `JList`?

```
Pacjent p = new Pacjent("Blosom", "Polo");
ListModel<Pacjent> model = new DefaultListModel<Pacjent>();
pList = new JList<Pacjent>(model);
```

---

```
public class Pacjent extends Osoba {

    private String imie;
    private String nazwisko;
    public ArrayList<Ubezpieczenie> ubezpieczenia = new ArrayList<Ubezpieczenie>();


...}
```

Answer (score 3):

You add element to the model. Instead of writing

```
ListModel<Pacjent> model = new DefaultListModel<Pacjent>();
```

write

```
DefaultListModel<Pacjent> model = new DefaultListModel<Pacjent>();
```

and just call its `model.addElement(element)` method.